# Is it correct to say "voluntary work"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Is it correct to say **voluntary work** when referring to the work that is being done by volunteers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* work that is done voluntarily, but it is *usually* referred to as **volunteer work**.

I, personally, have never encountered it being called *voluntary work* but apparently it is in use:
[image]

Comment: The phrase _voluntary work_ could be used in other contexts. (Just because it registers on the Ngram doesn't means it's being used in the context you are expecting). For example: "How are the bathrooms in the school being kept clean during this janitorial strike?" Answer: "Some of the teachers are helping out by doing some voluntary work." In a context like that, I'd **expect** to see _voluntary work_, not _volunteer work_, to differntiate it from labor given freely to the community or to a chartiable organization.

Comment: @J.R. True. My attempt to eliminate some false positives by using "doing some" may not be 100% successful, but I did peruse the results (as I always do) before posting. For example I found: https://books.google.com/books?id=pC4UgZTnSIsC&pg=PA90&dq=%22doing+some+voluntary+work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dFaoVJ2bLozVoASHwIDYDg&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22doing%20some%20voluntary%20work%22&f=false where the context and sentence is:  "Interview Question: What have you been doing since you left your last job. The best answer will be [...] that you have been doing some  voluntary work.

Comment: I perused the results, too, and found plenty of hits that matched the context. I posted my comment more for the general case than for this particular instance.